# Chromium not playing live youtube videos and other online streams

Tags: video, streaming, chrome

This is posted in order to provide an answer.

Details about the initial problem are [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/437245/32012).

[image]

It involved not being able to play Youtube live streams, Tweeter live streams, Vimeo non-live streams and many other online video in neither Chromium or Opera. (Now I have found a fix for Chromium that I am posting here, while I keep the other question for Opera only.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg` (as indicated in an answer under the linked question) this was not fixed; but installing`chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra` instead (installing one package removes the other)  for the purpose of playing Vimeo videos (as indicated [here](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015677227-Troubleshoot-player-error-messages)) solved for Chromium all the problems I had with both Opera and Chromium (not playing live streams and a lot of other non-live online video).

(N.B The problems were solved only for Chromium, not for Opera.)